# Input value not transferred over to python script

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-2.7, cgi

Idea is to write user's input to a text file on the server.

I have `input text` form and a `button` which submits form value:

```
<input type="text" id="playername" name="searchbox" placeholder="Your name">
<button id="givename" onclick="writename();">Submit</button>
```

On click `JS` function calls python script:

```
function writename() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/~......./test.py",
    });
}
```

Script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi
page = cgi.FieldStorage()
searchterm =  page.getvalue('searchbox', "test")    
results = open("history.txt", "w")
results.write(searchterm)
results.close()
```

Problem is text file always contains `test` value meaning only text form value is not passed and the rest works as expected. Directory rights are set correctly.

What could be a possible reason for this as I've been struggling with this block the whole night already?

Thanks

---

Solution:

The problem was with AJAX executing python script but not sending any data. Working version is:

```
function writename() { 
    $.ajax({ type: "POST", 
    url: "/~......../test.py", 
    data: { searchbox: $('#playername').val()}, 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: If you add value="woop" to the input box attributes does your text file then contain woop?

Comment: No, it still contains a "test" value

Comment: Can you try using:
    searchterm =  page.getfirst('searchbox', "test")
instead? If that doesn't work, I'm out. :p

Comment: Unfortunately, it still captures a "test" value, but thanks anyway

Comment: There are too many things which could go wrong. Simplify the test for debugging. Try first to make it work without ajax, i.e. add `<form action=".../test.py" METHOD="GET">`. Then try with `method="POST"`. If you make those work, then you'll know the problem is in javascript and not in python.

Comment: @zvone This is what I was doing previously and both methods worked nicely. The thing is I am confused of what could be wrong in     JS as it only has to call a python script what it actually successfully does ("test" value is written)

Comment: @O.Barinov OK, so the problem is in JavaScript. But you are showing a lot of python code and only `$.ajax({ url: "/~......./test.py",});` in JavaScript. Is that all JavaScript you have? That is not sending any data to `test.py`. And what is that `$`? Is that jQuery?

Comment: @zvone Thank you for pointing this out. The problem indeed was with JS not sending any data. Final version looks in this way: function writename() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/~......../test.py",
        data: { searchbox: $('#playername').val()},
    });
}

Comment: @O.Barinov Write your solution as an answer to your question. That way, if anyone encounters the same problem, they can see the solution which worked.